# Is it OK to ask questions about the capacities of a module?

Tags: discussion, recommendation-questions

I am looking for solutions to solve a problem with data and I am considering to learn `numpy` and `pandas` (Python modules to handle data).

This is quite an investment and I would like to make sure that it will fit with my specific needs (I have two well-defined problems). I have read the tutorials and watched introductions but the modules are large and versatile, so applications are not obvious.

Is it OK to ask a question of the type "I have such ans such data structure and would like to manipulate it in `pandas` to get such and such result. Would `pandas` be the right choice?" (together with the fact that I am willing to learn, just do not want to spend time on a otherwise useful module but which would not do the job)?

Comment: I'm afraid that will be primarily opinion based. It would help if you have one specific issue that you know need to be addressed, give that a try and when stuck ask about solving that issue while you state you expect similar things in the future. Answers will solve your actual issue and maybe warn you that you're using the lib at the edge of its capabilities.

Comment: @rene: it is not really opinion based: I could turn the question into "I have such and such data and want to manipulate it to have such and such result. How to do that with `pandas`? This shows zero research and will be destroyed with a flamethrower. The problem is that, to take an analogy, I need to go to work. I can try a bike to see if it will be useful and since it is a simple device I will know quickly if it works. I could also try a Boeing 747 but it will take me a long time to just realize that there is no landing strip at my work's.

Comment: Just go for the 747 but don't forget to bring your parachute....

Comment: It's opinion based because asking if it's the "right" choice is like asking if it's the "best" choice instead of just asking if it's possible to use pandas to solve your problem. It would probably be safer to try to ask in chat.